# MS Access - data type mismatch in the criteria expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a cascading entry in a form but i am getting data type mismatch in the criteria expression.

I have Table DeviceManufacturer_Table that has a ManufacturerName Column and a Helpfiles Hyperlink Column.
I then have a table  DeviceProductName_Table that has a lookup column for the device Manufacturer, i then want the next column to auto fill with the help files hyperlink. I Have created the form from the DeviceProductName_Table and
I Have tried the following but cannot get it to work-

```
Helpfiles = DLookup("HelpFiles","DeviceManufacturer_Table","Manufacturer =" & Manufacturer)
```

I thought it may be that the the lookup field for the manufacturer in the DeviceProductName_Table auto sets to number and the Manufacturer field in DeviceManufacturer_Table is short text but i have tried deleting the relationship and setting the data type to short text but i still get the same error?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo on the question there are quotes around the table name.

Comment: Create a new query with this SQL: `SELECT HelpFiles FROM DeviceManufacturer_Table WHERE Manufacturer = 5`. Does this query work? If not, the query editor should give you a hint as to why not.

Answer (score 0):

Manufacturer is most likely a string, thus:

```
Helpfiles = DLookup("HelpFiles","DeviceManufacturer_Table","Manufacturer ='" & Manufacturer & "'")
```

Comment: paste as is above nothing happens, if i delete the single quote after Manufacturer=, i get a "syntax error in the string query expression 'Manufacturer =5". the manufacturer i tested it on was record ID -5.

Comment: Helpfiles = DLookup("HelpFiles","DeviceManufacturer_Table","Manufacturer ='" & Manufacturer & "'") works if i change the manufacturer name to be the primary key in the DeviceManufacturers_Table. THanks for your help.

Comment: You should always have an autonumber as the primary key. Perhaps you just didn't have a unique index on Manufacturer.